# Best Method to pass a variable through functions in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a node app where I am parsing a tweet and using it to search for songs and then storing the song into a database.  I would now like to then store the tweet in the database.  Currently I am passing the var from the first function all the way through to 3 other functions and then storing the tweet.

My question is what is the more elegant/proper method for doing something like this.

Thanks for all education and help.

My code currently works and looks like this.

```
function start(Tuser, x) {
    T.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: Tuser, count: x}, function (err, data) {
        data.forEach(function (values) {
            var tweet = values.text;
            splitTweet(tweet);
        });
    });
}
function splitTweet(tweet) {
    var arrayOfTweets = tweet.split("-");
    var ArtistsStr = arrayOfTweets[0];
    var SongStr = arrayOfTweets[1];
    var SongNm = SongStr.split("playing");
    var Song = SongNm[0].trim();
    var ArtistsNm = ArtistsStr.replace(/\//g,"+");
    var ArtistsNm = ArtistsNm.trim().replace(/ /g,"+");
    res = /@/g.test(ArtistsNm);
    if (res) {
        console.log("Advertisement")
    } else {
        SoundSong(ArtistsNm, Song, tweet);
    }
}
function SoundSong (A, S, tweet){
    var SoundKey = "SHHH_ITS_A_SECRET";
    S = S.replace(/ /g,"+");
    A = A.replace(/ /g,"+");
    var url = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=' + SoundKey + '&q=' + A + S +'&limit=1';
    http.get(url, function(res){
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk){
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            if(typeof obj.errors != 'undefined'){
                console.log('ERROR: ' + obj.errors[0].error_message);
            }else{
                ParseSoundSong(obj, tweet)
            }
        });
    });
}
function ParseSoundSong (obj, tweet){
    if(typeof obj[0] != 'undefined'){
        var id = obj[0].id;
        var SongName = obj[0].title;
        var uri = obj[0].uri;
        var SongDate = moment().format('l h:mm:ss a');
        if(typeof uri === 'undefined'){
            uri = 'null';
        }
        var Songs = myFirebaseRef.child(id);
         Songs.set({
             uri: uri,
             SongName: SongName,
             Date: SongDate,
             Tweet: tweet
         });
    }else{
        console.log(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is out side of the rules.  there are many questions asking about the most pythonic way to do something that are not on hold and is basically what this user is asking only for Javascript.

Comment: I voted to reopen because there are plenty of answers on how this can better be architected that are not primarily opinion-based.  Folks here seem to react to the work "best" and automatically assume all possible answers must be opinion-based.  StackOverflows own wording says that primarily opinion-based questions are: `answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise`.  There are many possible answers to this question that are simply useful alternative ways to structure the code that solves the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is causing you to have to pass the `tweet` around from one function to the next is that you're doing nested function calls where you call `A()` which calls `B()` from inside it which calls `C()` from inside it which calls `D()` from inside it which finally needs the tweet data.  If, instead, you restructure your code so that `A()`, `B()`, and `C()` are functions that carry out an operations and return their results, then you can conceptually do it like this:

```
var tweet = ...
var someResult = A(...);
var nextResult = B(...);
var anotherResult = C(...);
D(tweet, ...);
```

Or, because one of your functions is asynchronous, you can use a callback to do it like this:

```
var tweet = ...
var someResult = A(..., function(results) {
    var nextResult = B(...);
    var anotherResult = C(...);
    D(tweet, ...);
});
```

This has the advantage of your functions `A()`, `B()` and `C()` become more useful pieces of code because they just carry out a specific operation and return the result rather than they are hardwired into a sequence of multiple calls.  I'll work on a specific example using your code.

Here's an idea for how that could be structured (untested, obviously):

```
function start(Tuser, x) {
    T.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: Tuser, count: x}, function (err, data) {
        data.forEach(function (values) {
            var tweet = values.text;
            var tweetData = new ParsedTweet(tweet);
            if (tweetData.isAdvertisement) return;
            getSoundInfo(tweetData.songNm, tweetData.artistsNm, function(err, data) {
                if (err) return;
                var soundInfo = parseSoundSong(data);
                if (!soundInfo) return;
                var songs = myFirebaseRef.child(soundInfo.id);
                songs.set({
                    uri: soundInfo.uri,
                    SongName: soundInfo.SongName,
                    Date: soundInfo.Date,
                    Tweet: tweet
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

function ParsedTweet(tweet) {
    var arrayOfTweets = tweet.split("-");

    this.tweet = tweet;
    this.artistsStr = arrayOfTweets[0];
    this.songStr = arrayOfTweets[1];
    this.songNm = this.songStr.split("playing");
    this.song = this.songNm[0].trim();
    this.artistsNm = this.artistsStr.replace(/\//g,"+").trim().replace(/ /g,"+");
    this.isAdvertisement = /@/g.test(this.artistsNm);
}

function getSoundInfo(songName, artistName, fn) {
    var soundKey = "SHHH_ITS_A_SECRET";
    var song = songName.replace(/ /g,"+");
    var artist = artistName.replace(/ /g,"+");
    var url = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=' + soundKey + '&q=' + artist + song +'&limit=1';
    http.get(url, function(res){
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk){
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            if(typeof obj.errors != 'undefined'){
                console.log('ERROR: ' + obj.errors[0].error_message);
                fn(obj.errors);
            } else{
                fn(0, obj);
            }
        });
        res.on('error', function(err) {
            fn(err);
        });
    });
}

function parseSoundSong(obj) {
    if(typeof obj[0] != 'undefined'){
        var result = {};
        result.id = obj[0].id;
        result.SongName = obj[0].title;
        result.uri = obj[0].uri;
        result.Date = moment().format('l h:mm:ss a');
        if(typeof result.uri === 'undefined'){
            result.uri = 'null';
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh got ya...I think, how would function B access what function A returns?

Comment: @FPcond - when there is an async operation, you access the return result with a callback.  See the code example I've added to my answer.

Comment: ok give me a few and ill test it.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am getting an error at  this.artistsNm = artistsStr.replace.... sorry I dont understand the function of this.tweet and what not so I am have trouble checking the function.

Comment: I corrected a typo on that line.

Comment: I had to change one line from var song = songName.replace(/ /g,"+"); to var song = songName[0].replace(/ /g,"+");

thank you for your help.  Can you explain why I had to change the line for it to work and also what does !! do in front of /@/g?

Comment: !! turns anything into a boolean (true or false) 0 it's a double `not`.  In this case it isn't needed because `.test()` already returns a boolean.  I will remove that.

Comment: one more edit...getSoundInfo(tweetData.song, tweetData.artistsNm) that fixes the need for var song-songName[0]  Thanks for your help @jfriend00 it works awesome now!